# How to derive the Galilean transformation for magnetic field B without taking help of special theory of relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, relativity

I have seen in some texts that the Galilean transformation of the magnetic field across inertial reference frames is given by:
$\vec B'= \vec B - (1/c^2)(\vec v\times \vec E)$. Every where it is stated that it can be derived using Galilean transformation. However I have never found it derived using **only** Galilean transform. (i.e. without taking help of Lorentz transformations).
The other equation concerning Galilean transformation of electric field:
$\vec E'=\vec E + (\vec v \times \vec B)$ has been seen derived by only Galilean transformation (i.e. by invariance of Lorentz force) very elegantly in many texts. Is it possible to derive this equation $\vec B'= \vec B - (1/c^2)(\vec v\times \vec E)$ by only using Galilean transformation?

Comment: See related question: [What is the Galilean transformation of the EM field?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/344893/what-is-the-galilean-transformation-of-the-em-field)

Comment: *I have seen in some texts* Please give titles and authors. This claim just sounds wrong to me. For a treatment of this topic, see Marc De Montigny, Germain Rousseaux, "On the electrodynamics of moving bodies at low velocities," http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0512200

Comment: The subtlety is that the Galilean transform isn't unique; there are two different possibilities, in the so-called electric and magnetic limits. That's why, to avoid confusion, it's almost always best to start from the Lorentz transformations and take either limit.